# Configure DHCP snooping with no option 82 on a pure layer 2 Juniper ex2300 using ELS

Tags: cisco, juniper-junos, juniper-ex, dhcp-snooping

I have a Juniper ex2300 switch in a mostly-cisco environment (no MIST). On my cisco devices, I have DHCP snooping configured per vlan, with option 82 disabled on the access-layer switches because they are bridging the traffic through another switch before reaching the DHCP relay.

To simplify the topology I'm looking at: At the access layer I have a L2 Juniper switch, which will be connected to a L2 Cisco distribution switch, connecting to the (cisco) DHCP relay.

Is it possible to enable a pure layer 2 version of DHCP snooping on a Juniper access switch using ELS, complete with disabling option 82? How would I go about this?

Comment: "_Is it possible to enable a pure layer 2 version of DHCP snooping..._" You may want to reword that because pure layer-2 has no concept of DHCP or even IP.

Comment: While very different from IOS, Juniper has extensive documentation. DHCP snooping is available on various versions / platforms for both ELS and non-ELS.